# Density of sin(k) where k is an integer

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Consider the set $A=\{\sin k:k\in\mathbb Z  \}$. I want to know whether this set is dense in $[-1,1]$.

I have a hunch that this problem can somehow be reduced to the approximation of $\pi$ using rationals, although I don't know how to make a connection.

Comment: Just a thought: maybe it is more easy to prove that set $\{e^{ki}\mid k\in\mathbb Z\}$ is a dense subset of the unitcircle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint.**

Consider the set $S=\{k+2\pi u | (k,u) \in \mathbb{Z}^2\}$. S is an additive subgroup of the reals. And you probably know that the additive subgroups of the reals are either closed (and have a least positive element) or dense.

$S$ cannot be closed as this would imply that $\pi$ would be rational. So $S$ is dense. As $\sin$ is continuous, $\sin(S)$ is dense in $[-1,1]$. As $\sin(A)=\sin(S)$, $\sin(A)$ is also dense in $[-1,1]$.